# post request errors "description not found" 404

Tags: python, json, http, telegram

I'm tiring to send some files to telegram, but the program receives the  errors 404.

This is my code:

```
import json
import requests

chat_id ="-"
TOKEN = "--"

data = {
    "chat_id": chat_id,
    "document": json.dumps([
        {"type": "document", "document":"attach:path_to_file"},
        {"type": "document", "document":"attach:path_to_file"}
# paths are like C:\\a\\b\\c\\d.jpg
    ])
}

files = {
    "photo1.png" : open("path_to_file", 'rb'),
    "photo2.png" : open("path_to_file", 'rb')
}

temp = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN + "/sendDocumentGroup", data=data, files=files)

print(temp.json())
```

The error appears as below:

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 404, 'description': 'Not Found'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a group of files, you'll just need to alter the `type`.

The `media` key from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747647/how-to-send-some-files-with-telegram-bot-in-python) should stay.

So use the following `data`:

```py
data = {
    "chat_id": chat_id,
    "media": json.dumps([
        {"type": "document", "media": "attach://photo1.png"},
        {"type": "document", "media": "attach://photo2.png"}
    ])
}
```

[image]

---

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75753104/post-request-errors-description-not-found-404/75755445?noredirect=1#comment133637331_75755445), you're using `sendDocumentGroup`, but you'll need `sendMediaGroup`. The `sendMediaGroup` works for files and images.

Comment: thanks but it steal errors  description: 'not found'    `data = {
    "chat_id": chat_id,
    "media": json.dumps([
        {"type": "document", "media": "attach:C:\\Users\\...\\0.jpg"},
        {"type": "document", "media": "attach:C:\\Users\\...\\0.jpg"}
    ])
}
files = {
    "photo1.png" : open("C:\\Users\\Achak\\Desktop\\graphiccs\\typhoone\\outcome\\0.jpg", 'rb'),
    "photo2.png" : open("C:\\Users\\Achak\\Desktop\\graphiccs\\typhoone\\outcome\\1.jpg", 'rb')
}

temp = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TOKEN + "/sendDocumentGroup", data=data, files=files)
`

Comment: I wondered if I could get some peace of advice from you.

Comment: Please see my edit, you're using the wrong method.

Comment: thank you so much, i made a mistake. youre code works correct.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please consider upvoting / accepting the answer to show the community that the answer has been useful, and will give some rep to both the questioner and answerer.