# how to send an image group with telethon in telegram in python

Tags: python, file-upload, telegram, telethon

hey I'm trying to send some images to a group in telegram using telethon to do it with my own account not a bot. but I have a little problem. it errors some how that I think some where I made a mistake in initializing something.
the code is:

```
filenames = ['C:\\Users\\Achak\\Documents\\GitHub\\typhoone\\qq\\0.jpg','C:\\Users\\Achak\\Documents\\GitHub\\typhoone\\qq\\1.jpg']
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            # Upload the file
            result = await client.upload(filename)
            media = InputMediaPhoto(result)

            # Send the file to the group
            await client.send_file(group, media)
            print(f'Sent {filename} to group with ID {group_id}')
        except PeerFloodError:
            print('Sending too many messages, stopping...')
            break
```

and this is the error:
`telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MediaEmptyError: The provided media object is invalid or the current account may not be able to send it (such as games as users) (caused by SendMediaRequest)`

I tried changing the location of image to the code container folder bot nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload your file with `client.upload(filename)`, you don't need `InputMediaPhoto`, you can just use the result of `upload` to `send_file`.

From the [documentation](https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/examples/telegram-client.html#sending-messages-with-media):

```
file = client.upload_file('photo.jpg')
client.send_file(chat, file)                       # sends as photo
```

So in your case, just use the `result` variabel as the paramter:

```
result = await client.upload(filename)
client.send_file(group, result)
```

Comment: thak you.but i sends my images is images :) i mean i want to send them in a file group like wht you showed me here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyqBo.png

Comment: To send a group, pass an list of files: `send_file(chat, [ file_1, file_2 ])`. To not send as images, but files, use the following option: `force_document=True`.